# Why happen this with Angular ActivatedRoute?

Tags: angular, routes

I implement a role guard in my Angular 11 project, when i was coding i got this doubt:

Why when inject ActivatedRoute in constructor i didn't get route data?

code:

```
constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute) {}

canActivate(): boolean {
  this.route.data.subscribe(res => console.log(res));
  return true;
}
```

console:

```
{}
```

But, if i pass the ActivatedRoute by params through canActivate(), i get them

code:

```
constructor() {}

canActivate(route: ActivatedRoute): boolean {
  console.log(route.data);
  return true;
}
```

console:

```
{role: Array(2)}
```

why happen this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Angular CanActivate guard decides, if a route can be activated,  this is because canActivate looks for all guards return true for  navigation to continues.

If any guard returns a UrlTree ( route serialized state ), the current navigation is cancelled and a new navigation begins to the UrlTree returned from the guard.

More [Info here](https://angular.io/api/router/CanActivate#description)